# How can I check if I have a particular dependency installed?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, python, dependencies, xubuntu

I'm trying to install a program (Python). The program lists the dependencies it needs and the commands to run to install them in its Readme file.

What's the easiest and quickest way to check if these dependencies already exist in my computer before trying to install them?

[Xubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB]

Comment: Just run the command to install them. It's going to do nothing (not even connect to internet) if you have all of them.

Comment: And if I don't?

Comment: Then tries to go to the internet and install them.

Comment: Cross-posted on [Ubuntu.se]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290394/

Comment: Are you trying to install it from sources (i.e. published by the dev directly) or are you trying to install from official xubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Run a simulation of the intended package installation as a normal user without prefacing the command with `sudo` and without installing anything. Open the terminal and type:

```
apt install --simulate package-name
```

where you replace `package-name` with the name of the package the installation of which is being simulated. The above command will list all the additional dependency packages that would be installed to in order install this package.

Run a similar command to simulate the installation of a .deb file. Open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the directory that contains the .deb file (package-name.deb in this example), and run the following command.

```
apt install --simulate ./package-name.deb
```